# Android in app billing how and where to specify paid feature charges

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Can anyone explain how does in-app billing process works for Android?
Do I need to upload two different apk (free and paid) to Play store and link buy button click in free app to paid version on Play store, but in this case will free app get replaced with paid app when user purchases paid one? How to achieve this?

If I give buy button in my free app which enabled purchase of paid full version (extra features) then how does this purchase works? Is it that upon activity startup I get some event when will tell me if app is purchased or not. Based of which I can enable paid features in my code. If yes Will this kind of logic work when user is offline? and how?

Appreciate if someone could clear my confusion with sample code. I have successfully run Google's sample code but not able to understand if I upload my app as free app how and when do I need to mention amount paid features?

Comment: You will need to implement in-app purchase in your android app simpley, just make a googled and you will have many tutorial

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to upload two different apk (FREE & paid) to play store .

This depends on the use case. If you want to give your users different app that has limited and Pro features that differs majorly then you should put two different apk's in market.

Otherwise , If your app has Free and Paid content you should include In-App purchases.

> in this case will free app get replaced with paid app when user
>   purchases paid one ? How to achieve this.

No , Your app won't get replaced , you will only get payment successful/failed response from Google play , you have to save that information in your app shared preferences and manage your app flow accordingly.

> If I give buy button in my free app which enabled purchase of paid
>   full version (extra features) then how does this purchase works?

Your application accesses the In-app Billing service using an API that is exposed by the Google Play app that is installed on the device. The Google Play app then conveys billing requests and responses between your application and the Google Play server. In practice, your application never directly communicates with the Google Play server for purchases. Instead, your application sends billing requests to the Google Play application over interprocess communication (IPC) and receives responses from the Google Play app. Your application does not manage any network connections between itself and the Google Play server.

> If yes Will this kind of logic work when user is offline? and How.

To complete in-app purchase requests, the Google Play app must be able to access the Google Play server over the network. But after initiating a purchase request , you can save your payment response in shared preference for maintaining offline status.

> Appreciate if someone could clear my confusion with sample code. I
>   have successfully run google's sample code but not able to understand

You should first start by reading the API docs [Google Play In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and [Selling In-app Products](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) ,

> if I upload my app as free app how and when do I need to mention
>   amount paid features ?

After that follow the steps to create In-App products on [Google play account](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) and run the API sample for those products.(There are plenty of tutorials online). Also you can take a look at official website for [Establishing In-app Billing Products for Sale](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html)

Enjoy!